# why does this dot notation produce different outputs in axios and express

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

So I am making a geo tool app using `reactjs`. The design for this part is this, user submit a city's name. The submission will trigger a **post** request, and the request will loop through a city list.json file to find the matched city and will return the city's geolocation in such format

```
{
      "id": 6167865,
      "name": "Toronto",
      "state": "",
      "country": "CA",
      "coord": {
        "lon": -79.416298,
        "lat": 43.700111
      }
}
```

the post request at front end is

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/weather/loggedin/citySearch',searchCity)
.then((res)=>{
console.log(res.data.coord)//<--here
})
```

the post request at server side (backend) is

```
router.post('/loggedin/citySearch',(req,res)=>{
    let cityname = req.body.cityName
    let countryname = req.body.country
    fs.readFile('../public/weatherdata/citylist.json', (err,data)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
            res.send('Wrong.')
        }else{

            user_info.cityName = cityname
            let selected_city=(JSON.parse(data)).filter(i=>i.name===cityname && i.country===countryname)
            console.log(selected_city[0].coord)//<--and here
            res.json(selected_city[0])
        }
    })

})
```

Can someone tell me why I get different outputs when using

```
console.log(res.data.coord) //used at axios and it returns the coordinates
```

vs.

```
console.log(res.selected_city[0].coord) //used at server.js and it returns undefined
```

I was wondering if axios and express take dot notation differently?

Comment: what does `console.log(selected_city[0])` on your server side returns?

Comment: thank you sir.....I figured it out, in my original code i never typed in '[0]'

Comment: i Am sO sTuPiD...ehhh

Comment: haha nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

Disregard the question
I never put selected_city[0]in my code